# MS Excel Interop - Prevent Sign In Modal When Opening a Restricted Access Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am using MS Excel Interop to parse information from a collection of Excel files. If one of these Excel files has [restricted access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/information-rights-management-in-office-c7a70797-6b1e-493f-acf7-92a39b85e30c), a Windows sign-in modal opens and pauses my program. I would like to skip over these files so that this modal does not appear.

[image]

My current code, with various settings to block any Excel warnings:

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
application.DisplayAlerts = false;
application.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(filePath, UpdateLinks: 0, ReadOnly: true, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true, Password: "fakePassword");
```

I encountered a similar issue with password protected Excel documents, but was able to prevent the enter password modal by setting a fake password in the `.Open` code above. This causes an exception to be thrown when a file is password protected, which I then catch and the program continues on to the next Excel file.

I was hoping the [WriteResPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia) option for the Open method would work similarly, but even if I specify this, the Windows sign in still appears.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly happy with this solution, but I have found a workaround for avoiding MS sign-in modals (and many other modals) prior to opening an Excel document.

Before opening the Excel document with MS Excel Interop, I conduct a "zip test" where I zip up the file into a temporary directory, attempt to extract it, and then immediately delete that directory.

```
private void ZipTest(string xlsxFilePath, string tempDirectoryPath)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectoryPath);
        string zipPath = ZipFile(xlsxFilePath, tempDirectoryPath);
        using (ZipArchive zip = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            zip.ExtractToDirectory(tempDirectoryPath);
        }
        Directory.Delete(tempDirectoryPath, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(tempDirectoryPath))
        {
            Directory.Delete(tempDirectoryPath, true);
        }
        throw ex; // Do whatever you want
    }
}

private string ZipFile(string filePath, string destinationDirectory)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string zipFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".zip");
    string destinationPath = $"{destinationDirectory}\\{zipFileName}";
    File.Copy(filePath, destinationPath, false);
    return destinationPath;
}
```

Zipping and extracting the file will fail if the workbook has restricted access, is password protected, or otherwise can't be written to. This prevents the MS sign-in modal because the excel doc is never opened.

Note that this only works on xlsx files. Any xls files need to be converted to xlsx first.